# Angular Service Data Not Loading

Tags: angular, web-services, rxjs, httprequest

I have an Angular project. Data from the service is loaded when I click somewhere. For example, when I delete a row in the table, it is successfully deleted in the background. However, if I click any button on the page, it gets deleted.
The data I received with get is loaded and lost. When the page refreshes it reloads.

```
  GetAllVessels(){ 
    return this.http.get(this.baseUrl+'Vessel/GetAllVessels',httpOptions).toPromise()
     .then(res => this.AllVessels=res as Vessel[])
    } 

  <tr *ngFor="let p of SystemAdminServicesService.AllVessels">
```

I found a different solution with the rxjs library and the async statement.

Comment: Your question doesn't make much sense. What exactly is the problem? What gets deleted? How do you delete it? Also, I suggest you don't convert to promise, use Observables.

Comment: I can see the data from the service on the console screen. But on the page, for example, it only loads if I click an empty area in the list or click a button.

Comment: Do you have change detection onPush?